# Automatic Timestamp on google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp

I'm new to Google Sheet and I'd like to know if there's any way that a timestamp would automatically be input on column A when someone types something on column B

Comment: There are ways, but it would require you to use google apps script to code the solution. You can find tutorials here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials.
If that's too much you now have the "Show edit history" for each cell, manual yes but allows you to see when cells were edited and by whom

Comment: If you do sometihng like `=arrayformula((if(ISBLANK(B1:B), ,TO_TEXT(now()))))` the timestamp would update on every edit, so yes, you would need a script if you want to prevent this.